# What does this means in this context ? 武勲をあげる

Tags: meaning, expressions, reading-comprehension, japanese-to-english

**武勲をあげる**

**Much thanks if anyone can help me understand its meaning.**

Context: The author is describing a general who was being invited to participates in a battle.

孫堅は左軍司馬としてこの戦に参加している。

朱儁に請われて参戦したものだが、孫堅自身に黄巾賊の思想はあまりよく理解できなかった。

**ただ、こうして参戦することで武勲をあげる機会を与えられたことに対する意気込みのほうが強かった。**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

機会【きかい】 is an important part of that, too. It helps to address this part of the sentence as if it were a noun.

So, in this sentence 武勲【ぶくん】をあげる機会【きかい】 means *a chance to demonstrate distinguished military service​*.

Comment: so "a chance to prove his talent on the battlefield" ?

Comment: @rimini7631 Yes.